# how to take over someone else's open Pull request?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am inheriting another person's open Pull Request.
I want to checkout the branch, make changes, commit and push.

git branch -r shows:

```
origin/users/xxx/28322253
```

I tried:

```
git checkout origin/users/xxx/28322253
```

but got a message `You are in 'detached HEAD' state`.

What is the correct way got switch to that branch?

Comment: You can't really take over someone else's PR unless you have the ability to push to the original branch location.  You could create a branch from their work, add your own stuff and propose it in a new PR, but I'd be careful about doing that.  You should really work with the owner of that work to figure out how to handle it.

Comment: I don't think a Pull Request really has an owner.  It might have a submitter.  If you have repo security to push onto the branch the existing PR will just get an update.  There are reasons why you can't work with the original owner (quit or let go).  Also, depending on the reviews that might have already happened on a PR, it might not be advisable to lose that review history/approvals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git checkout users/xxx/28322253
```

This checkout creates a local branch that tracks the remote branch.

Comment: ... and then push into that remoge branch, the PR will update.